# How can we show default wheel date picker open in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, datepicker, ionic2, uidatepicker

I need to implement the wheel date picker functionality in my code but my requirement is little different from normal that I need to the wheel roller date picker default open so I can select the date wisely

I tried to modify the default date pickers code to use in an ionViewDidload method in which it will open default with the method but unfortunately, it is not working

(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-tpFsYFNgklg/XNUKtZMG4nI/AAAAAAAABOA/P_lUhnLyiQgq9bnHslJABEEr8rMICVipwCK8BGAs/s0/2019-05-09.png)

please check the image this is my requirement